# CMake Error when building RealSense Python wrapper: Cannot specify sources for target "PRIVATE"

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, cmake, realsense

### Background

I would like to make a program using the RealSense depth camera in python 3.6. However, the wrappers are only avaialable for python 2, but according to their [github page](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/wrappers/python), could be built by users themselves:

> Windows users can install the RealSense SDK 2.0 from the release tab to get pre-compiled binaries of the wrapper, for both x86 and x64 architectures. (Note that these binaries are built with Python 2.7, and cannot be import using Python 3).

and also in one of the [issues](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/980):

> Unfortunately no, the only way at the moment is by building it from source. We are planing to provide a PyPI package that will allow you to simply pip install pyrealsense2 and it will have both python 2 and 3 support, but it is still work in progress...

Therefore, I decided to try and build it myself before reverting to python 2.x.
I followed the explanation on the [github documentation](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/wrappers/python#windows), which is a little too basic for someone who never really built anything. I puzzled together quite a bit, but I have hit a wall where the CMake documentation, stackoverflow, and generic google searches did not help me. It could be due to my lacking understanding, but I decided to reach out and see what I can learn.

### My issue

Currently I'm stuck with the error:

```
CMake Error at core/CMakeLists.txt:3 (target_sources):
  Cannot specify sources for target "PRIVATE" which is not built by this
  project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (include)
```

I tried understanding the CMakeLists.txt which looks like this:

```
target_sources(${LRS_TARGET}
    PRIVATE
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/streaming.h"
        ...
)
```

After looking in the documentation I decided to change `PRIVATE` into `PUBLIC`, but this results in the same error (but with public instead of private).

Literal internet searches (in between quotation marks) for this error return nothing, and other trials didn't help me any further.

I'm now assuming the issue is with the `${LRS_TARGET}` variable, but I have no idea where to look. I can't seem to find out where it should be defined, and setting it as an "Entry" in the CMake gui makes the error say "value" instead of "PRIVATE".

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

### My Settings

I'm using cmake-gui, and setting the following:

- "Where is the source code:" = D:/librealsense-master/src
- "Where to build the binaries:" = D:/librealsense-master/bin
- BUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS = True
- -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE = D:/Anaconda3/python.exe

For the rest, I did nothing, and only some Entries appear made my CMake itself.

### Issues I Solved

As someone might be trying the same thing as I am, I will mention the steps I took until now:

1. The first issue I got was that I needed to add the following line at the top of the main CMakeLists.txt file:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
   ```
2. Then I found out I needed to install Visual Studio
3. Then I found out that only Visual Studio was not enough, and that I needed to add the *Desktop development with C++* "Workload"

Comment: You have specified **wrong directory** as a *source* one. Correct directory is `D:/librealsense-master/` (this is the top directory of the project on GitHub). BTW, absence of `cmake_minimum_required` should signal that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Damn, I tried that when working in the installed folder (However, that did not contain other CMakeLists.txt files, and errored on that). It did not occur to me to redo this test in the downloaded master folder. Thanks a lot, @Tsyvarev! I now get other errors, let's see if I can solve those!